# VB.net app will only run as Administrator only

Tags: vb.net

I made a few improvements to code that has been functioning without issues.  On the development, the app runs with a problem.  Installed on a test computer and it does not run unless I right click and run as administrator.  The below code is where gets not running as Administrator.

The for loop is adding file names to a list.  Administrator the program just ends no errors just quits.  i counter gets to 3 of a total of 6 files.  Never gets through to post the message "Did it make it here".  But does post the message inside the for loop.  i counts to 3.  If run as admin then no issues.  All file names are short and basic with no special characters.  The files locations is Application.CommonAppDataPath.  The loop is called from Form load.

Hoping someone could tell me what is going on.

```
     Try
        Selected_Machine = XMLReadSetting("Machine", "Selected", "Selexx")

        For i = 0 To UBound(files)
            MessageBox.Show("Here 2 i " & i & " File Name" & files(i))
            cboMachine.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files(i)))
            If Selected_Machine = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files(i)) Then
                cboMachine.SelectedItem = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files(i))
            End If
        Next
    Catch err As SyntaxErrorException
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show("Did it make it here?")
```

Comment: I would say the program isn't just quiting and there is an unhanded exception happening.  Perhaps using a try catch block with some logging might help.  You also mentioned in the past it was working without issue before you've modified.  Perhaps show us the original code, maybe we can spot the difference

Comment: The code I had added is on a different form and is only triggered with a click of a button.

I will try the try catch,

Comment: I edited the code above to show the addition of the try catch.  No error posted and still does not reach the message box "Did it make it here?"

Comment: Maybe try Catch err As Exception.  Catch err As SyntaxErrorException will only catch SyntaxErrorExceptions

Comment: Thank and thank you.  The catch is at least reporting an issue with Access to the path.  Strange that it works with 2  files then fails on the 3rd.

And it is failing on a file that is not even in the folder.  Explains why is has an Acess to the path error.

Comment: Have you looked at files you are opening, the security settings may be different for that 3rd one. Try to open it as the user

Comment: The file that is failing on is not one of the files in the list.  So now do dig into what my array has a file that is not in the folder.

Comment: Are you able to show us how you build your file name array?

Comment: Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(SettingsFolder & "\EditConfig")

Comment: Digging deep the error is really coming from inside the text changed of the list box. And the file assess error is an XML file used to store basic settings.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Inside the for loop it make a change that calls the text changed event of the list box.  In the text changed event I write data to a settings file.  The settings file did not have write access.  Not sure how that happend but problem solved

Thank you all for the help.